# Traefik ReplacePathRegex does not route correctly

Tags: traefik

I believe this to be a bug. I'm trying to use `ReplacePathRegex /**ddd**/(.*) /$1` to point my path `ddd` to my service on the root port. The service can still be resolved on the host root path.

```
example.com/ddd
```

is the same as

```
example.com/
```

This should not be the case. `example.com/` should yield a 404.
Using the other modifier or stripers this works as expected.

Has anyone seen this error?